# MapView not displaying google Map only grey tiles

Tags: android, android-mapview

I am extending an existing android application that is using google API V1 but when I run the application the map shows only grey grid and no map , the problem is that I read that google map API V1 is deprecated and is no longer used , so Is there a way that I can run this application and display google map instead of recoding the application with Google map API V2 ? . Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Map v1 displays grey tiles grid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302500/google-map-v1-displays-grey-tiles-grid)

Answer (score 0):

According to this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/ link, it says there is backward compatibility to existing Android applications which use the API v1 keys. Anyway the key should not be deprecated. Only you cannot request for new keys for API v1. However check against your manifest if its having all the required permissions addressed. Specially uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"